# CakePHP save field to associated table

Tags: cakephp

I have my 'PatientCase' model with a hasOne relationship to my 'PatientCaseOrder' model. (This table simply stored the patientCase id along with an integer position)

I am using an ajax function to update the position fields in 'PatientCaseOrder' using the function below in my PatientCase controller

```
public function update_position(){
        Configure::write('debug', 0);
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->loadModel('PatientCaseOrder');
        $list = $_POST['list'];
        $errs = false;
        if($list){
            foreach($list as $position){
                $id = $position[0];
                $pos = $position[1];
                $this->PatientCase->id = $id;

                if(! $this->PatientCase->PatientCaseOrder->saveField('position', $pos))
                     $errs = true;
            }
        }

        echo json_encode ($errs);
    }
```

I am passing to it an array containing the PatientCaseId and position.
The code produces a 500 server error, where am i going wrong, or am i taking the wrong approach to this?

NOTE: I previously had the position field in the PatientCase model, and this line of code worked with the above segment of code

```
$this->PatientCase->saveField('position', $pos)
```

Comment: `$PatientCaseOrder` is not an object, it's an array. Try `$this->PatientCase->PatientCaseOrder->saveField('position', $pos)` instead.

Comment: I tried that, still not working -> Updated the question code

Comment: put debugging back on and see what the problem is. Also where is `$id` being set?

Comment: have you tried `$this->PatientCase->saveField('PatientCaseOrder.position', $pos);`

Comment: Yes that did not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your controller function for better debugging:

change to `Configure::write('debug', 2);`

add `$this->layout = 'ajax';`

and change : `if(! $this->PatientCase->PatientCaseOrder->saveField('position', $pos))
                     $errs = true;`

to:

`pr($this->PatientCase->PatientCaseOrder->saveField('position', $pos)); die;`

and then in your ajax function log the callback

`console.log(returned_data);`

and check for errors.